# Php вывод:кракозябры.Select(html),php и тип  Date,Datetime в Mysql

Tags: дата, mysqli, php, запрос, datetime

1. Ситуация: Отправляем на почту человека ссылку на активацию. Человек нажимает и оказывается на странице активации.

Контроллер:

```
<?php .... if(...){$inf='Активированы';}else{$inf='Ваша ссылка не верна.';}>
```

Показ:

```
<?php echo 'Кряк'.$inf.''?>

//Слово Кряк нормально выводится, а вот значение $inf выводится крякозяброй.
```

Как убрать кракозябру?

1. Есть day,month,year.

Они в разных selectax.

```
if(isset($_POST['day'],$_POST['month'],$_POST['year'])){
$date_birth = array($_POST['year'],$_POST['month'],$_POST['day']);
$date_birth = implode('-',$date_birth);
```

И потом в запросе прописал

```
date_birth=".(int)$date_birth."
```

Не добавилась в бд. как сделать так чтоб добавилось?

3.Есть скрытый input date_reg.

```
$date_reg = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

И потом в запросе прописал

```
$date_reg=".(int)$date_reg."
```

Не добавилась в бд. как сделать так чтоб добавилось?

Comment: P.s. Первую проблему решил. Оказалось не преобразовал на без BOM. Остались другие вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

1. Решение.

   > if(isset($_POST['day'],$_POST['month'],$_POST['year']))
   >     {
   >         $date_birth = sprintf("%04d-%01d-%02d",
   > $_POST['year'], $_POST['month'],
   > $_POST['day']);}

И потом в запросе прописал

```
date_birth='".$date_birth."'
```

3.Решение.

```
$date_reg = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

И потом в запросе прописал

```
date_reg='".$date_reg."'
```